# neo4j - find child nodes with property value is slow

Tags: neo4j

I have a graph with approximately 1 million nodes.
The graph represents a catalog tree (spare parts). Maximum deep is about 6.
A node have a filter property that can have any value, even empty. This filter property is used to filter the catalog for the user.
What I want is to ask a question like this when I click a node (any level):
"for each child node, tell me if any of its children (any level) has a filter attribute with a value of ...".
With my query I takes about 12 sec for each child to get the result. Should not this scenario be an ideal use case for neo? Shouldn't it be way faster?

I can send the nodes and relations as text files if you want the data.

my query is something like this:

```
start n=node(3)
match n-[:PARENT_ITEM;1..6]->x
where x.filter="something"
return count(x)
```

I'm running on a Windows Azure Large server (4 cores, 7Gb ram) and i haven't done any configurations after neo installation.